# AWS ELB returns status 504 after 10 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm getting 504 status code returns when requesting my load balancer, it then transfers the request to a fargate container.

This happens when launching simultaneous calls, some return 200, some 504.

I tried raising the Idle timeout to 60 seconds in the UI as well as in the aws cli but my requests keep timing out after 10 seconds.

Is this normal behavior ? Is their another way to raise this threshold ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

504 Gateway Timeout means that the ALB couldn't reach the backend, this is also quoted [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/504-error-alb/): "The load balancer failed to establish a connection to the target before the connection timeout expired (10 seconds)."

Raising the timeout (which is an idle connection timeout) has no effect. Please try to troubleshoot the connection between the ALB and the Fargate Container.
The first and best check is to see if the TargetGroup is healthy.

Comment: My target group is healthy, but depending on the context I could be launching around 20 to 30 requests silmataneously, my Fargate doesn't crash or anything. It's just that's it is beeing busy with the first let's say 15 requests, so the last ones are failing due to the task not responding. Maybe I should allow more memory, i've tried retriggering the requests that fail but it seems like a workaround solution. I wanted to see if their is a cleaner way to make these requests work

Comment: These are important details you left out in the original question. So the requests are reaching the backend and the backend doesn't respond to the connection requests? Then the 10s 504 timeout do make sense. If the backend doesn't scale as much, you might have to spawn multiple Tasks or make it scalable. Doesn't sould like an ALB problem to me.

Comment: can you change the default 10 seconds?? is there a way to do it, i need to queue the requests, my service can only open 32 threads and then the other ones are gateway timeout responde in a 10tps test

Comment: @EduardoNicolalde best to open a new question with more details. 10s is fix, maybe the ASS Support can change it, but we can’t.

Answer (score 0):

Seems more a connection issue between the ALB and some of the instances, that causes an intermittent Gateway Timeout. 
Check if the subnets where the instances are deployed are equally configured and, if you use a Network Load Balancer, [enable Cross-Zone Load Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/network-load-balancers.html#cross-zone-load-balancing).

Comment: I tried enabling Cross-zone load balancing of my target group, it didn't change the behavior

Comment: Cross-zone load balancing is a configuration on Balancer level, not Target Group, are you sure?<br/>
Check the routing tables and the base configuration of the subnets (NAT Gateway if they are private and non auto-assign public IP, IG if they are public): are all the same?<br/>
All the instances in the Target Group are healthy, have you checked the logs?